# Do all docker images have minimal OS?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am trying to learn Docker and for that referring to online materials. I came to know that there is official hub of images which we can pull, and run a container.

The repos are available at `https://hub.docker.com/` , part of screen shot:

[image]

In this diagram we can see the official images of ubuntu, httpd, mysql (and so on).

## My question is:

Do all these images have "minimal OS" on which they run. For example, if we consider `httpd` image, does it have the needed OS on which it runs?

Comment: You should take a look to official Docker documentation : https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: You need programs which in turn needs libraries etc.  These come as files in the docker image, and are invoked when needed.  Docker provides the kernel they talk to.  For a Java Docker machine you _could_ get along without anything else but the JVM and the libraries it needs.

Comment: Does it mean we can have an image without any OS?

Answer (score 27):

From my understanding images are built in a layered architecture from a parent image. So we have a parent image and then the changes for this image is one more layer above parent image. If you see dockerfile for an image you can see something like this

```
FROM node:6.11.5
```

This **node:6.11.5 is a parent image** for our current image.

If you check dockerfile of parent images you will find they are somewhere in the hierarchy follow **from base image**.

This base image is basically an OS without kernel but has only userland software based on the different linux distributions(eg, centos, debian). So all the images uses the host OS kernel. Hence, you cannot install a Windows container on a Linux host or vice-versa.

So basically all images are layered changes on the base image which is an OS without kernel.

Please find below links for further information:

https://serverfault.com/questions/755607/why-do-we-use-a-os-base-image-with-docker-if-containers-have-no-guest-os

https://blog.risingstack.com/operating-system-containers-vs-application-containers/

If you need to create a base image you can see the steps here.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 15):

Here's the answer: ***"Containers,"*** **in all their many forms, are an** ***illusion!"***

Every process that is "running in a container" is, in fact, **running** ***directly*** **on the host operating system.**  But it is "wearing rose-colored glasses."  *It thinks* that it knows what its user-id is ... but it doesn't. ‍♂️  *It thinks* it knows what the network looks like.  What the filesystem looks like. ... ... ...

And, it can afford to think that way, because nothing that it is able to see would tell it otherwise.

... But, nothing that it sees is actually the physical truth.

"Containerization" allows us to achieve the essential technical requirement – *total isolation* – at very-considerably less cost than "virtualization."  The running processes see what they need to see, and so "they need be none the wiser."  Meanwhile, the host operating system, which is aware of the actual truth, can very-efficiently support them: it just has to maintain the illusion.  The very-expensive "virtual machine" software layer is completely gone.  The only "OS" that actually exists is the host.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you.

Comment: Best Answer IMO.

Answer (score 6):

Most images are based on a distribution as you can see it in their Dockerfiles. Except for the distribution images themselves. They have a different base-image, which is called [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/scratch/).

You can review the images they are based on when you visit the project's page on DockerHub, for example https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/

Their Dockerfiles are referenced and you can review them by clicking on them, e.g. the first tag "2.2" refers to [this file](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/53654452889ae3af537eef2dbb981ccac6fb907f/2.2/Dockerfile). The first line in the Dockerfile is `FROM debian:jessie` and shows, that it is based on a Debian image.

It is widely used to have a separated tag with the postfix `-alpine` in it to indicate, that [alpine linux](https://alpinelinux.org/) is used, which is a much smaller base-image than the Debian image. This leads to a smaller image of the httpd image, because the base-image is much smaller.

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea is that the whole image is completely stand-alone running on hardware/virtualization layer. And thus (the pro:) also cannot be influenced by anything else than that is part of the image.

Every image contains an complete os. Special docker made OS's come with a few mega bytes: for example [linux Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) which is an OS with 8 megabytes!

But bigger OS like ubuntu/windows can be a few gigabytes. Both have their advantages since docker cuts an image up in layers so when you use anbase image twice (FROM command, see N20 Answers) then you will only download this layer once.

Smaller OS has the pro of only needing to download a few megabytes. but for every (linux) Library you want to use, you will have to download & include yourself. This custom made layer then is only used in your own image and thus is not re-used in other images and thus creates a customer extra download layer & megabytes people will have to download to run your image.

If you want to make an image from nothing you can start your dockerfile with:

```
FROM scratch
```

But this is not advised, unless you really know what your are doing and/or you are hobbying around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So is it always that images inevitably have minimal OS? I am still not clear :(

Comment: Not all images are created equal. For example: Bitnami's php-fpm:7.2.1-r0 image is 253MB in 15 layers. kreable/php70:latest is 1.21GB in 45 layers. So, even if they do have the same base image, the actual layering, and how you clean up after yourself as you install dependencies will have an impact on the final image size. It is a balance between reusability (but probably bigger layers) and minimalism (but probably not reusable enough to warrant the additional effort).

Comment: I'm really curious as to what use case there would be for `FROM scratch` to get anything running in this, i.e. something that works out 1+1, would you still need to include an OS (alpine is given as the example here)?

Comment: Something doesn't seem right about this. Docker uses process-isolation, so it runs directly on the host OS.  It's not the same as a VM. Therefore, the docker image wouldn't include a whole OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of these answers miss the point. Explaining what you can or may do does not answer the question: do all docker images need an OS?

After a bit of digging, the answer is no.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

There's no OS defined in this Dockerfile. Only a precompiled binary hello world app

Also here
https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch

Also in this question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/755607/why-do-we-use-a-os-base-image-with-docker-if-containers-have-no-guest-os

An answerer makes this statement:

> why do we base the container on an OS image? Because you'd want to use some commands like (apt, ls, cd, pwd).

So often the OS is just included because you might want to use some bundled low level tools or SSH into it to do some things.

Comment: So do u mean that if the host OS already have these commands (apt, ls, cd, pwd), hence there is no need to base the container on an OS image.

Comment: Nothing you run in the host will affect the container unless there is a service in there listening for it. So... that's not really what I mean. What I mean is if you don't want to run OS commands inside the container, you apparently don't need to include an OS. This is more of a conceptual thing than actually being useful though.